# Are there jobs where one needs knowledge about chaostheory?

Tags: soft-question

I am beginning with my masters degree in mathematics next semester and one possibility is to specialize in chaostheory. When I am done with the degree I will likely leave the university and so I am asking myself where I could use this knowledge about chaostheory. Or maybe this is a very pure subject which has no big applications in the working world ?

Comment: I use a lot of chaos theory in my work in signal processing for automated driving, if you need an example. Quantitative finance also uses chaos theory, as does a lot of scientific computing,

Comment: All of maths is applied maths... :-D

Comment: What would be an application of chaostheory in scientific computing ?